# set up firebase in react native for IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I am working on IOS firebase messaging in react native for several days ,but unfortunately it doesn't work .
when I use use_frameworks! :linkage => :static in Podfile ,it conflicts with react native map after searching a lot I use below lines instead of use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

```
  pod "FirebaseCore" , :modular_headers => true
  pod "FirebaseCoreExtension" , :modular_headers => true
  pod "FirebaseCoreInternal" , :modular_headers => true
  pod "FirebaseInstallations" , :modular_headers => true
  pod "FirebaseMessaging" , :modular_headers => true
  pod "GoogleUtilities", :modular_headers => true
```

the error fade but the firebase message not receive in IOS simulator
What should I do ?